# org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: object is an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before merging

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I know there are many of questions regarding this error. I tried them already and nothing was solved.

I have a dtoDevice which is already in the DB. I got the data from the DB. Now I want to add dtoValue object to that device and it doesn't work.

I have the following DTO classes

```
@Entity
public class DtoValue {
   @Id 
   @GeneratedValue
   protected int id;

   private int value;

   @ManyToOne
   private DtoDevice dtoDevice;

  ... /* Getters and Setters */
}
```

and

```
@Entity
public class DtoDevice{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    protected int id;

    String deviceName;

    @OneToMany(cascade= CascadeType.REMOVE)
    List<DtoValue> values;

          ... /* Getters and Setters */

    public void addValue(DtoValue dtoValue){
        if(dtoValue != null)
            values.add(dtoValue);
        dtoValue.setDtoDevice(this);
    }
}
```

When I try running this code:

```
          ... /* em = EntityManager */

    try{
        em.getTransaction().begin(); 


            DtoValue dtoValue = new DtoValue();

            dtoValue.setValue(1);
            /* Even if I try saving dtoValue here (em.persist/merge(dtoValue)) It doesn't work */

            **// THIS dtoDevice is already in the DB - I want to modify it**
            dtoDevice.addValue(dtoValue);
            /* Even if I try saving dtoValue here (em.persist/merge(dtoValue)) It doesn't work */


        /* persist doesnt work, since dtoDevice is already in the DB */
        em.merge(dtoDevice); 

        em.getTransaction().commit();
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        em.getTransaction().rollback();
        showConnectionError(e);
    }
```

I get the error:

```
org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: object is an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before merging: **not_important**.model.DtoValue
```

I tried many methods and followed some tips and nothing until now.

Comment: Try to persists `dtoValue` first. and then `dtoDevice`.

Comment: @Jens I commented on the code "/* Even if I try saving dtoValue here (em.persist/merge(dtoValue)) It'd doesn't work */"

Comment: Save it before you add it to dtoDevice.

Comment: @Jens It doesn't matter if I save before of after adding to dtoDevice. Same error.

Comment: Have you called em.flush() after saving the `dtoValue`

Comment: Use `@OneToMany(cascade= CascadeType.ALL)` instead of `REMOVE`

Answer (score 1):

Hi try to save DtoDevice first then assging dtoValue  to the DtoDevice and then save DtoDevice.

Answer (score 1):

When you go to to save DtoDevice, it has a Collection of unsaved DtoValues (the root of the problem). You could address in several ways:

1 - Add PERSIST to the list of cascaded operations from DtoDevice to DtoValues like so:

```
@OneToMany(cascade= {CascadeType.REMOVE, CascadeType.PERSIST}) 
List<DtoValue> values;
```

2 - Save each new DtoValue before addingn them to the DtoDevice like so:

```
DtoValue dtoValue = new DtoValue();
dtoValue.setValue(1);
DtoValue savedDtoValue = ... save it here
dtoDevice.addValue(savedDtoValue);
```